# Passing an Array or List to @Pathvariable - Spring/Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, path-variables

I am doing a simple 'get' in JBoss/Spring. I want the client to pass me an array of integers in the url. How do I set that up on the server? And show should the client send the message?

This is what I have right now.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{firstNameIds}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test(@PathVariable List<Integer> firstNameIds)
{
     //What do I do??
     return "Dummy"; 
}
```

On the client I would like to pass something like

```
http://localhost:8080/public/test/[1,3,4,50]
```

When I did that I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [firstNameIds] in @RequestMapping

Comment: You might need to use New Spring 3 UI Field Formatting http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC1/reference/html/ch05s06.html

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
GET http://localhost:8080/public/test/1,2,3,4

@RequestMapping(value="/test/{firstNameIds}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test(@PathVariable String[] firstNameIds)
{
    // firstNameIds: [1,2,3,4]
    return "Dummy"; 
}
```

(tested with Spring MVC 4.0.1)

Comment: Does jersey support this pattern?

Comment: Yes ,Jersey supports this but in different way using PathSegment

Comment: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20056,20056"

Comment: But how to distinguish between /{id} and /{ids}? Tried to do it like `@GetMapping(value=["""/{id:\d+}"""])` and `@GetMapping("""/{ids:\d+[,\d+]+}""")` but now Spring tells me that *my-url/123* is ambigous (which isn't the case)...

Comment: @spyro I guess you could check if `ids.size() == 1`?

Comment: @atamanroman: Thank you, but the desired return type is either a single object or a collection, so I need two distinct methods.

Answer (score 53):

You should do something like this:

**Call:**

`GET http://localhost:8080/public/test/1,2,3,4`

**Your controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{firstNameIds}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test(@PathVariable List<Integer> firstNameIds) {
     //Example: pring your params
     for(Integer param : firstNameIds) {
        System.out.println("id: " + param);
     }
     return "Dummy";
}
```

Comment: Confirmed the above works with Spring 4.2, likely with most of Spring 4.x. This is also the most Java-like answer offered.

Comment: Does Jersey support this pattern?

Comment: got 400 error code, this small change worked for me. `public String test(@PathVariable("firstNameIds") List<Integer> firstNameIds) {`

Comment: I am sending data as ["first","second"].Can you tell how to accept it at controller using PathVariable?

Comment: @SachinHR : List<String>

Answer (score 12):

if you want to use Square brackets - []

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/public/test/[1,2,3,4]

@RequestMapping(value="/test/[{firstNameIds}]", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public String test(@PathVariable String[] firstNameIds)
{
    // firstNameIds: [1,2,3,4]
    return "Dummy"; 
}
```

(Tested with Spring MVC 4.1.1)

Comment: This works great when wrapping in square brackets, but what if I'm required to send a list wrapped in curly braces? that always seems to blow-up on me...

Answer (score 3):

Could do @PathVariable String ids, then parse the string.

So something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{firstNameIds}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test(@PathVariable String firstNameIds)
{
     String[] ids = firstNameIds.split(",");
     return "Dummy"; 
}
```

You'd pass in:

```
http://localhost:8080/public/test/1,3,4,50
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, put this in your code (Add @PathVariable)  :

```
@GetMapping(path="/test/{firstNameIds}",produces = {"application/json"})
public String test(@PathVariable List<String> firstNameIds)
{
     return "Dummy"; 
}
```

You'd pass in:
http://localhost:8080/public/test/Agent,xxx,yyyy