# Spring request mapping catching part of uri to PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, rest

I need something similar to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java)
So my path would be: `/something/else/and/some/more`
I would like to map it like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest(String theRestOfPath){ /***/ }
```

Or

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest(String[] theRestOfPathArr){ /***/ }
```

The thing is ... I would like everything matched by `**` to be passed to the method either:
1. as a string (theRestOfPath = "/else/and/some/more"),
2. or as an array (theRestOfPathArr = ["else","and","some","more"]).

The number of path variables can vary, so I can't do:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something/{a}/{b}/{c}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest(String a, String b, String c){ /***/ }
```

Is there a way to do that?
Thanks :)

---EDIT---
The solution I ended up with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public TextStory getSomething(HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String URI_PATTERN = "^.*/something(/.+?)(\\.json|\\.xml)?$";
    String uri = request.getRequestURI().replaceAll(URI_PATTERN, "$1");
    return doSomethingWithStuff(uri);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to use `query string parameters` instead? with `(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> params)`

Comment: Nope, this is against rest principles, these values are not optional, they have to be there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include an `HttpServletRequest` as an argument to your method, then you can access the path being used. i.e.:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
    String pattern = (String) request.getAttribute(
                     HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    String path = new AntPathMatcher()
            .extractPathWithinPattern(pattern, request.getServletPath());

    path = path.replaceAll("%2F", "/");
    path = path.replaceAll("%2f", "/");

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(path, "/");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        String token = st.nextToken();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: accepting as this led me to the right solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's feature in spring MVC which will do parsing for you. Just use @PathVariable annotation.

Refer: [Spring mvc @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803731/spring-mvc-pathvariable)

Comment: you can't catch @PathVariable with /**, it can only catch named variable (/{a} for example)

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk: Thanks for pointing out. It won't work in that case