# pass a list of long with spring rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am using spring boot, spring v4.2.5

I am trying to pass a list of long.

My controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/members/{memberId}/payments/{paymentsId}/process/{paymentMode}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void processPayment(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId, @PathVariable("paymentsId") List<Long> paymentsId, @PathVariable("paymentMode") PaymentModeEnum paymentMode) {
    paymentService.processPayment(paymentsId, paymentMode);
}
```

Controller never gets called with this link.

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/members/6/payments/105,106/process/ATM
```

But it does with this

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/members/6/payments/105/process/ATM
```

Is it possible to pass a list of long?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java

Answer (score 0):

Use the array of longs instead of the list and than simply convert it into a list if you need one.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/members/{memberId}/payments/{paymentsId}/process/{paymentMode}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void processPayment(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId, @PathVariable("paymentsId") Long[] paymentsId, @PathVariable("paymentMode") PaymentModeEnum paymentMode) {
    paymentService.processPayment(Arrays.asList(paymentsId), paymentMode);
}
```