# How to pass array as PathVariable in spring rest template?

Tags: arrays, spring, resttemplate, url-parameters, path-variables

I want to pass array as path parameter in URL.

My code is as follows:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/[{location_id}]" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getAllProcessInstances(@PathVariable("location_id") String[] location_id) {
         try {
        return processService.getAllProcessInstancesByLocation(location_id);
         }catch(Exception e) {
             return "error=>"+e.getMessage();
         }

     }
```

When I try to test this through browser I am getting following error:

> http://localhost:8088/super-admin/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/[%7B8,9%7D]
>
> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Wed Jul 11 12:54:55 IST 2018
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Could not get HttpServletRequest URI: Illegal character in path at index 67: http://localhost:8088/super-admin/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/[%7B8,9%7D]

How to pass the array in url? I want to pass as follows:

```
http://localhost:8088/super-admin/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/[7,9,11]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an Array or List to @Pathvariable - Spring/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/{location_id}" ...
```

not

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/[{location_id}]" ...
```

So for example the following controller would return `["a","b","c","1","2","3"]` when calling `GET http://localhost:8080/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/a,b,c,1,2,3`:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/getAllProcessInstancesByLocation/{locationId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String[] getAllProcessInstances(@PathVariable String[] locationId){
        return locationId;
    }
}
```