# Delete array using list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I want to implement endpoint for deleting a list if IDs

```
    @DeleteMapping("/contracts/remove/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> remove(@PathVariable Integer id) {     
        contractsTerminalsService.delete(id);        
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

How I can send a list of IDs like this:

```
POST /api/contracts/bulk_delete
with body { ids: [1,5,6] }
```

What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Here is a complete solution https://pastebin.com/Q0Awn1CQ

Answer (score 2):

Just use `List<Integer>` and your request should be like  `/api/contracts/bulk_delete/1,5,6`

```
@DeleteMapping("/contracts/bulk_delete/{ids}")
public ResponseEntity<?> remove(@PathVariable List<Integer> ids) {     
    // Do whatever you want with id        
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

For more reference visit [Passing an Array or List to @Pathvariable - Spring/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java)