# @PathVariable UUID... ids with comma-separation doesn't work: a 400 response is returned

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using the findByAllIds method of crud repository in spring boot. I would like to pass the list of id's with a comma seperating them in my @pathvariable, the id's are of type uuid so whenever i do that, i get "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string" error.

Comment: You should show us some of your code so we can actually help you. Read the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add the code in your comment to your question (you can edit it)

Answer (score 1):

From the code in your comment I cannot see anything indicated as a @Pathvariable, but even if it is, you mentioned that you are passing multiple UUIDs separated by a comma. However, you only list a single UUID parameter in your method call. If you would attempt to pass multiple UUID strings into that, I would indeed expect the error you're getting, that is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string`

Have you tried making the @Pathvariable an array? i.e. `UUID[] ids`? Or as a list, i.e. `List<UUID> ids`? Both are possible according to [Passing an Array or List to @Pathvariable - Spring/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java)