# API naming conventions for list of objects

Tags: rest, api, naming-conventions

Basing on the naming conventions found here : https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/ ,  I have a particular question to which I can not find an answer.

Taking the example of customers and accounts where sub-collection resource “accounts” of a particular “customer” can be identified using the URN “/customers/{customerId}/accounts” , how do I find accounts for multiple customer IDs? What are the naming conventions for such a case?

Is the only option to use filters? eg: customers/accounts?customerId=12,22

Answer (score 0):

I tend to avoid filters and keep everything as a `urn` and keep the implementation of the backend system hidden. e.g. this

```
customers/accounts?customerId=12,22
```

means the client needs to know that customers are represented in the system by a variable called `customerId`. Clients shouldn't need to know that. They just need to know that customers have numbers, IMHO anyway.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java) shows a solution for your situation, which would look like:

```
customers/accounts/12,22
```

although to keep it in line with the domain, where customers have ids and associated accounts, it would look like:

```
customers/12,22/accounts
```

and your backend framework would give you the list of customer 'numbers' from the url and at that point they become `customerId`s.

Not all frameworks may support arrays in paths but pick the right tool for the job and you can design your API to be elegant and a good match for your domain.

Comment: I like the 1st example (query string) best. Especially the 2nd is bad since it's not clear that those are customer IDs. Could be account IDs, which will bite you, if they are ever introduced.

Comment: yes, that's why I prefer the third one as it's clear they're related to customers

Comment: thank you for your inputs! I think we'll stick to the query string, not used to the arrays in the middle of a uri..