# Pass array of ids with axios to spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, axios

I have encountered an issue.
I need to pass an array of ids that looks like: `[1,2,3,4]` from my frontend with axios to my spring boot mvc controller.

I want to retrieve the array from `@RequestBody` in my controller.

How would I do it?

As already mentioned, I will post my code and what I have so far.

In my vue component, my axis call:

```
axios.put('{{ myUrl }}', {
              genreIds: this.form.selectedGenres
            })
```

In my mvc controller, my method:

```
@PutMapping("/url")
    Song myMethod(
            @PathVariable Long songId,
            @RequestBody Long[] genreIds
    ) {
        System.out.println(genreIds);
        //My other code
    }
```

And all I am getting is a `bad request status 400` from my Server

Comment: What did you already tried? Do you use a common content type like `application/json`? With these information nobody can answer your question...

Comment: Hello, I haven't specified any content type, so I am using the default: `application/json`. I will post my code and update my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an Array or List to @Pathvariable - Spring/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623258/passing-an-array-or-list-to-pathvariable-spring-java)

Comment: no it doesn't, I wanted the to get the form data over the @RequestBody, but I already solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```java
@XXXMapping(value = "/url")
public ResponseEntity controllerMethod(@RequestBody int[] arrayWithIds){
//normally use arrayWithIds in Methodbody
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I tried it out, but I am getting 'bad request status 400'. My axios request is probably wrong.

Comment: try to add in the PutMapping Annotation `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` and on the body in the axios `JSON.stringify(data_to_send)` and a third parameter in the axios like: `{headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'}}`

Comment: It still gave me bad request, but I got it to work. I used `@RequestBody Map<String, Long[]> genreIds`